# [Gitlab]Where can I find Gitlab Pages hosted on my private Gitlab instance?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I tried to set up Gitlab Pages, until now I finished uploading my static website files

```
Uploading artifacts...
coverage/lcov-report: found 77 matching files      
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=1038 responseStatus=201 Created token=QXJjgkf2
```

But I got no idea where my page hosted.

I took a glance at [this documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html#practical-examples) but it was still vague to me.

- I have a private Gitlab instance.
- My Gitlab entry is under http://abc.def.com (I configured a type A DNS to my host IP 111.111.111.111, a reverse proxy pointing at localhost:9000).
- My project `project1` is under my team `team1`.
- I have also configured DNS http://team1.abc.def.com to 111.111.111.111 , and there is a nginx reverse proxy on my server which http://team1.abc.def.com -> localhost:9000.

I assume I should see my static page available on http://team1.abc.def.com/project1 , but nothing was there. Where exactly are my pages hosted?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work, I have the same issue here!

Answer (score 6):

You have to activate the pages feature. In your gitlab.rb:

```
pages_external_url "IP_OF_YOUR_GITLAB"
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
```

There is a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dD8c7WNcc6s&feature=youtu.be
And the complete documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/pages/index.html

Comment: Jeremad, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to ask your sysadmin under which wildcard domain Pages is served: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html#gitlab-pages-domain

Then you'll know where your site was deployed to.

Example: on GitLab.com, all Pages domains are served under `*.gitlab.io`, therefore, your website will be deployed to `username.gitlab.io` (user/group site)  or to `username.gitlab.io/project-name` (project website).

You need to find out the wildcard domain of your GitLab instance and replace `gitlab.io` with it.

See also: Pages' limitations: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pages/introduction.html#limitations

Comment: OK, and plot twist - what if your username has a dot in it? For example `j.smith`? Would the address still be the same?
j.smith.gitlab.mydomain.io/project-name ? Or would it be jsmith wihout the dot or won't work at all?

Answer (score 0):

pages_external_url is the url of your website

You can set up a git-runner to pick the work for publishing your website. In this part you need to deal with .gitlab-ci.yml file

For the gitpage URL, you can find it under setting -> operate > pages, there should be a URL for the website. Usually is under namespace.example.com/projectname.

If you didn't see the page under the setting, it is usually a configuration issue. You just need to enable it, and re-congiure the gitlab.

Answer (score -1):

For gitlab pages to work, you need to put your website files (html, CSS etc.) in a folder named `public`.

Update your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with something like the following

```
pages:
  script:
    - mv coverage/lcov-report public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

Also, remember to name the job in question `pages`

Comment: Once you've done that where exactly are your pages hosted?

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas Have you set up Pages from an admin perspective? https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/pages/index.html